# Why browsers doesnt support on same TRANSFORM, BOX SHADOW.... CSS syntaxes?

Tags: html, css, syntax, cross-browser

I cant understand, why all browsers use different **TRANSFORM, BOX-SHADOW**, and etc...  syntaxes? :

```
-moz-transform:
-webkit-fransform:
-o-transform:
```

it's hard for programmer to code 4 same commands again and again...

Answer (score 1):

This is the way browsers implement not standardised features. Because the feature wasn't part of the standard when they implemented it, they made their own implementation and syntax.

Some IDE's (e.g. Visual Studio) can help you with this:
[image]